# Examples of instrumental variables for business problems (not rainfall!)

Tags: econometrics, supply-and-demand, elasticity, instrumental-variable

I have been learning about IV as a non-economist and I think I understand the examples I've seen which used rainfall as an IV for modeling the sales of crops or fish at an outdoor market.

However, for the problems that exist in my company, it's more difficult to imagine what IV might be appropriate.  Say, for business problems related to price elasticity and customer retention.

The instrumental variable should be predictive of supply but not demand, so could I use a measure of industrial production from a 3rd party market research company?  Or try to get a measure of the supply that was temporarily lost under Covid lockdown policies?

As an engineer, it feels weird to be in a position where my analysis relies on such a creative(speculative?) decision.